# I Cannot load ubuntu with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have installed both Windows 7 and Ubuntu. But today when I turned on my PC it showed an error regarding GRUB RESCUE. So I solved it referring to a site. The site told the following steps:

> If you have Windows 7:
>
> - Insert your Windows install disc
> - Press any key at the “Press any key to boot from CD or DVD” message    to boot from the disc Choose Repair your computer after you select
>     the language, time and keyboard method (for Windows 7 users)
> - Select your Windows installation drive (usually C:)
> - Click Next
> - Select Command Prompt in the System Recovery Options window
> - Write the following commands in the Command Prompt:
>
>   ```
>   bootrec /fixmbr
>   bootrec /fixboot
>   bootrec /rebuildbcd
>   ```
>
>   Press Enter after each command

After doing this steps my Windows 7 started loading without any problem, but I cant boot with Ubuntu now. Please help me with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The process you described appeared to have repaired Windows 7's boot manager which doesn't consider other OSes, just Windows.  I don't think you can Boot into Linux with Windows' boot manager.

To have the option for dual boot with the choice of Windows or Linux you'll have to install a boot manager like Grub.  Grub is the default Ubuntu boot manager.  So what you'll have to do is reinstall Grub.  Grub will give you a menu choice of all the installed OSes you have.  After you reinstall Grub, you'll have the choice of booting into Windows 7 or Linux.

There are a number of ways to Install Grub.

You can use this method to install Grub on your boot harddrive.  This will replace the Windows boot manager:

Boot to a live Ubuntu DVD and use the Try Ubuntu option.  From a terminal command run the following:

```
a) sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt # Make "sdaX" the partition that has Ubuntu install (i.e. /dev/sda2)
b) for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
c) sudo chroot /mnt
d) update-grub
e) if no errors skip this "e" section
     grub-install /dev/sdX (sdX is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda)
     update-grub 5) Reboot the system
```

Answer (score 0):

Boot using a live Ubuntu CD/USB. Install boot-repair using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Click on

> Recommended Repair

and wait. You will have to be patient as it can can a lot of time.